# How to get last inserted id when joining tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am joining three tables using following query

```
select a*,c.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 join table3 c on c.col2 = a.col2 where a.col3 = 1 and a.col2 = 1
```

I am getting more no. of rows then I require so I also used group by to filter results but I want rows that were inserted in last so I tried this

```
select t1.* from (select a*,c.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 join table3 c on c.col2 = a.col2 where a.col3 = 1 and a.col2 = 1) t1 left join (select a*,c.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.col1 = b.col1 join table3 c on c.col2 = a.col2 where a.col3 = 1 and a.col2 = 1) t2 on (t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.rowid<t2.rowid)
```

It gives me error

> ## 1060 - duplicate column name col2

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: don't select `*` for `a` and `c`. selec the required columns one by one explicitly

Comment: @GurV I tried to select specific columns. Query ran successfully but it returned zero rows.

Comment: Then problem is in the JOINS. please post some sample data and expected output in the question